# Redirect requests to a static S3 website using AWS route53

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

I have a static S3 website that was once ago delivered using CloudFront and S3. We rebranded the company and changed our URL, so I'd like to have all requests to https://business.magi.cash/ to be redirected to https://business.tutodigital.com.br. To achieve my goal I:

1. created a similar structure for business.tutodigital.com.br (which is now accessible and working)
2. deleted the magi.cash associated CloudFront distribution
3. changed the route53 entry so that the record associated with business.magi.cash is now a CNAME record pointing to business.tutodigital.com.br

It's not working though.

Any thoughts?

Comment: `It's not working though.` - we need more specific information about what's wrong. Please clearly explain what's not working about your attempt. We're more than happy to then help :)

Comment: Can you also please share your Route53 config (text + screenshot)?